# struct initialization

Tags: solidity, struct

I want to know how to initialize the structure created using 'struct' key word.

I can't see use of 'new'  key word in Solidity documentation.

Some body please guide me.

Zulfi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
struct Example {
    uint a;
    uint b;
    uint c;
}

Example public example;

function set1(uint _a, uint _b, uint _c) public {
    example.a = _a;
    example.b = _b;
    example.c = _c;
}

function set2(uint _a, uint _b, uint _c) public {
    example = Example(_a, _b, _c);
}

function set3(uint _a, uint _b, uint _c) public {
    example = Example({a: _a, b: _b, c: _c});
}
```

Comment: This means that there is no use of 'new' keyword for struct data type. Thanks for removing my confusion.

Comment: @zak100: No, the `new` keyword is used for instantiating a new contract, for example: `MyContract myContract = new MyContract(1, 2, 3);`. In other words, it is used for deploying a contract on-chain (i.e., from another contract) instead of off-chain (e.g., from a web3-based NodeJS script).